# Can't populate my JavaFX ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I cannot populate my JavaFX ComboBox that I have created from Scene Builder. Although I have searched, I cannot find a fix to this error.

None of the below examples work.

```
@FXML ComboBox ComboStatus;

@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rbs) {           
        ComboStatus.getItems().addAll("Single","Married");
    }
```

---

```
ObservableList<String> statusList = FXCollections.
            observableArrayList(
                    "Single",
                    "Married"
    );

@FXML ComboBox<String> ComboStatus;

@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rbs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ComboStatus.setItems(statusList);
    }
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Both code snippets are correct: if they are not working you have something else wrong somewhere. Create a [MCVE] and post it in your question.

Comment: what is your fxml? The code you've provided looks correct.

Comment: Strange. If you put a breakpoint on that line and run in debug mode, will the program stop there? And if you then execute the line, do you get any errors? Like e.g. the NullPointerExeption because the combobox's name is different in you FXML? BTW. I would rather use comboStatus (with lowercase 'c' at the beginning) than ComboStatus.

Comment: I tried making a minimal and it worked!.. Thanks or the help. I really didn't know what the problem was, but separating  controller for main and controller for fill-up form worked. I did combine them before to save java files but I guess it won't work that way...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of code that does work and hopefully helps:

The class that extends Application:

```
public class Test extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(Test.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new 
           FXMLLoader(Test.class.getResource("/test/MyExample.fxml"));
        AnchorPane pane = (AnchorPane)loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The controller class:

```
public class MyExampleController implements Initializable {

    //I think the problem with your code was that you did not use 
    //ComboBox<String>
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> cbxStatus;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        cbxStatus.getItems().addAll("Single", "Married");
        //you can make it so that an item is already selected
        //instead of no item being selected until the user clicks on the box 
        //to select
        cbxStatus.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    }    

}
```

Comment: Thankyou, but if you look at my second example, I did use <String>. I already did solve it as I have stated in the comment section of the above post, by making a "Minimal" or so they call it. Thanks anyway.